# How to update the Grapfiks(Text that is shown) of a Combobox in a Treeview?

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, treeview

To give a little Background. My Program is a WPF build up in the MVVM pattern i use Caliburn micro and for design MaterialDesign(should not be interesting for my Question)
I have a treeview that is created dynamically. Each Parent item that is in the Treeview has a combobox.

I create the Treeview out of a List named Items which is from the Type CustomItems.
Each customitem has a List of strings in which i save the children strings named Children.
Each customitem has strings. One string is named Fruit. I save the selection from the combobox in that string for each item.
When I start the Program each combobox has a text "Test" in it. The combobox has 4 hardcoded possible selectable words which are saved in a second List in the cutomitem called PossibleChoises.
The treeview Looks like the following

```
> Item1         [Test]˅
> Item2         [Test]˅
```

Now the user selects sth in the combobox. Lets say the User selects Apple than the treeview looks like that

```
> Item1         [Apple]˅
> Item2         [Test]˅
```

I have Button which calls the Function clear. The function should clear the Combobox. And the string Fruits of each item should be set to Test again. I managed to get that.
So when I Press clear the Fruits string of each item is set to Test but the view does not update.
The treeview still looks like that

```
> Item1         [Apple]˅
> Item2         [Test]˅
```

But Items[1].Fruit = Test
How do I update the text in the combobox to show Test again.
Here is my Code

```
<Treeview ItemsSource="{Binding: Items}" x:Name"ItemTreeView">
 <Treeview.Resources>
  <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type models:CustomItems}" ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
   <Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
     <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
     <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
     <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding ItemName}"/>

    <Combobox
     Grid.Column="1"
     ItemsSource="{Binding PossibleChoises}"
     Text="{Binding Fruits}"
    </Combobox>

   </Grid>
  </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
  <DataTemplate DataType="String">
   <Dockpanel>
    <TextBlock/>
   </Dockpanel>
  </DataTemplate>
 </Treeview.Resources>
</Treeview>
```

I cant post the whole class because its very big and would make the question to long. I hope I descripted the Class well enough. So when I load the file Fruits is "Test" and in my Program i set it back to "Test" but the UI does not update.
I only found the following but that is way to slow. My treeview has 1000 parents so the refreshing takes 10 sek or more

```
public void Clear()
{
TreeView treeview = (GetView() as ShellView).ItemTreeView;

foreach(CustomItem customItem in treeview.Items)
{
customItem.Fruits = "Test"
}
treeview.Items.Refresh();
}
```

Is there a way to Name the Combobox and use it like following

```
TreeView treeview = (GetView() as ShellView).ItemTreeView;

foreach(Combobox box in treeview.Items.Combobox)
 {
 Combobox.Text="Test"
 }
```

Thanks for you time and if i let sth unexplained i will happily add it

Answer (score 0):

Your `CustomItem` class, where the `Fruits` property that the `ComboBox` binds to is defined, should implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface and raise change notifications:

```
public class CustomItem : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _fruits;
    public string Fruits
    {
        get { return _fruits; }
        set { _fruits = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(); }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged([System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallerMemberName]
        string propertyName = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

You should not need or try to get a reference to a `ComboBox` element in a possibly (and likely) virtualized `TreeViewItem`.

Comment: How do I implement INotifyPropertyChanged if I´m already inheriting from sth else? I will try to implement your answer and will make an update here.

Comment: Like I showed you in my answer?

Comment: Yes but I cant use : INotifyPropertyChanged because I´m already inheriting sth else. Your answer still worked but I´m not sure why I did not need that

Comment: `INotifyPropertyChanged` is an interface that you implement. You can implement several interfaces...